# display color issue on MSI dominator laptop display

Tags: display, colors, color-management, color-depth

hi all i have this weird coloring on my MSI dominator laptop as shown below :
[image]
any idea of what causes this?? 
which is only seen in ubuntu not windows 10

Nvidia GTX1060 with 381.22 driver.

Comment: Are you using the Intel or the Nvidia graphics when this happens? If the latter which drivers have you installed?

Comment: i only have nvidia card it is not optimus laptop and i use

Comment: this laptop has only nvidia card non optimus and i use 381.22 driver. i also used earlier version of drivers but all has same issues. also the laptop has the GTX 1060 so i dont have many options in term of driver version